# Using jQuery to Load External Files

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to load an external file within my HTML, but nothing happens.

My HTML File

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Double Navigation Bar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Mainpage.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src= "mainp.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="nav1" id="nav1">
          <ul>
          <li><a href="SchoolHistory">School History</a></li>
          <li><a href="SchoolTimes">School Times</a></li>
          <li><a href="SchoolFees">School Fees</a></li>
          <li><a href="" id="reason">Why?</a></li>
        </ul>
  </div>
<div id="article" class="article"></div>
<div class="aside">Aside</div>
  <div class="footer">
        <p>Contact Number:  &bull; Email Address: </p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My js File

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("reason").click(function(){
        $("#article").load("Reason.html");
    });
});
```

This is the external file I'm trying to run. Reason.html

```
<H1>Reasons Page</H1>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please help by indicating if you see any Errors or details in your Console. Is it `reason.html` or `Reason.html` and is it at the same location as your current page? If it's in another folder, the relative path needs to reflect that.

Comment: `$("reason")` should be `$("#reason")`

Comment: Thank you that fixed the issue. Is there a way to write it so that I can do it for multiple links? Instead of writing it out multiple times?

Comment: @LinnoX Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69238253/edit) to show an example of which elements you want to update and which URLs you want to populate them with.